# Calculating combinations of subsets (Permutations and Combinations)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

*How many of the subsets of {1, 2, . . . , 9} have an odd number of elements? How many of the subsets of {1, 2, . . . , 9} have an even number of elements? You should observe something very interesting. Can you explain the math behind your observation?*

With 9 elements, we should have

$9\choose 9$ + $9\choose 8$ + $9\choose 7$ + $9\choose6$ +...+ $9\choose1$ = $512$ subsets.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint:What are the total number of subsets of the given set?What does all subsets with even number of elements,odd number elements tell you out of total number of subsets?

Answer (score 0):

The interesting observation they are looking for is that the number of odd and even subsets is equal. This follows from the fact that a subset can either have odd or even cardinality. Knowing this much, can you now evaluate what this number would be?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Hint

If there are $n$ elements, and you are forming a subset, then each of the elements either is or is not in the subset.  This gives $(2)^n$ possible subsets.  This includes the empty set which has $(0)$ elements [$(0)$ being an even number], and the entire set, which has $(n)$ elements.

Then, when $(n)$ is odd, you have a symmetry argument.  For each subset formed, the elements not chosen also form a subset.  Of the two subsets, one chosen, and one not chosen, exactly one of these two subsets will have an odd number of elements.

This implies that the solution is immediate, without any further calculation, simply by a symmetry argument.